# Meteor timesync package not syncing when changing client time

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I am using timesync v0.1.4 package with meteor v0.7.2 and with it have created a countdown timer. The problem am facing is that when I try changing the client system manually, the time retrieved by the package is the client time instead of server time. So, I tried calling the `TimeSync.resync()` function before the `TimeSync.serverTime()`, which causes the timer to come back in sync with the server after a split second of being wrong. During those split second, another message is showing which I have set to be shown when the timer has ended/not started.

Is there any way to show something like 'Resyncing' while the package is resyncing with server or a solution to this issue?

I know there is a method called `TimeSync.watchClockChanges()` in the subsequent version of the package. But I am in a situation that prevents me from using the latest version of the package.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am the maintainer of the timesync package.

When you change the client system time manually, the package is not returning the client time - it's just returning the current client time plus whatever the computed offset was.

It doesn't know that the client time has jumped unless you use the `watchClockChanges` function that we implemented in a later version, which looks for unexpected jumps in the system time across ticks.

The right way to do this would be to reset the clock offset to an undefined value when we notice that the clock has changed, and then `TimeSync.isSynced()` would reactively become false across a clock change. This would then revert itself when the sync is successful.

I've opened an [issue about this on GitHub](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-timesync/issues/6), and I'd be happy to help you with this. However, you should try to update your app to use the latest version of Meteor and this package.

Comment: I am now using the watchClockChanges function and it is working as expected by switching back to the actual time after a couple of seconds. Is there some way to show some 'Resyncing' message when this is happening?